# How to remove duplicate lines in two large text files by number of appearance?

Tags: python, duplicates, frequency

I have two large text files with same number of lines (9 million lines, about 12gb each file). So they cannot be loaded in memory.

Lines in these text files presented in table look like this:

[image]

I need to remove duplicates in ***A.txt*** and ***B.txt*** and leave only most frequent combination for each line from ***A.txt***. In case of 2 most frequent lines with same number of repetitions program should choose line that first appeared in text and remove all others.

In real files lines aren't just (A,B,C,D,...1,6,7,..) and each line has about 2000 characters.

Final text files presented in table should look like this:

[image]

Comment: If the texts are too large, you could try to hash them in advance to reduce their memory footprint. Then you will only need to find what row ids (Lines) match and keep the first one of them. This will be regardless of which process you use to sort in the end.

Comment: What exactly does "...and leave only most frequent combination" mean? Combinations of what?

Comment: Lets imagine that line in A.txt represents x, and line in B.txt represents function f(x). You cannot get different f(x) for same x. So I need to remove duplicate lines, and leave only most frequent f(x) for given x. In table example if x=A then f(x) = 1 or 2, but 1 is more frequent so this is solution.

Comment: How many *different* lines are in A and B?

Comment: To be exact there are 8397659 lines in each file, and 3253008 duplicates in file A.txt.

Comment: You say "You cannot get different f(x) for same x" however your sample input shows the value C paired with 7 and 9, so doesn't appear to be following that constraint. Regardless, consider using the `marshal` module which will allow you to create a dictionary-like file-based object that could be used to store intermediate results limited only by free disk space.

Comment: @martineau Think about that like mathematician. In file A.txt are x variables and in file B.txt are y=f(x) variables. For x variable you could get only one unique f(x), but more x variables can give same f(x). This is why B.txt files don't have unique values. I need to have all unique lines in A.txt files, but not in B.txt file.
Lines should preserve order - if you delete third line in A.txt, you should delete third line in B.txt too because they are connected as function in program where I need this data.

Comment: @martineau Yes, but this value C is example where you have same number of appearance. 7 appeared once, and 9 appeared once, so you should choose 7 because it appeared first. I wrote that in question.

Comment: Sorry. for thinking like a computer scientist, but I believe I finally get it. The issue is because you _do_ have different f(x) values for an given x, and you want to keep whichever f(x)  occurs most often (or the first if there's an equal number of them).

Comment: @martineau Just to make it clear, files A.txt and B.txt in the beginning are not following the statement "You cannot get different f(x) for same x". But after deleting duplicates there shouldn't be two f(x) for same x. This is goal.

Comment: @martineau Yes, that's right.

Comment: OK, good — I think using the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module would be a feasible way to do this that would allow processing arbitrarily large files. I suggest you try it. Note earlier I mistakenly said the `marshal` module — ignore that).

Comment: I'll try it, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Does the result really need to be sorted? You used the "sorting" tag but otherwise you don't say anything about it.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be sorted. I'm sorry, removed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can you avoid reading 2 × 12 GB into memory at once, but still process all the data?

By loading those 24 GB chunk by chunk, and discarding data you don't need anymore as you go. As your files are line-based, reading and processing line-by-line seems prudent. Having 4000-ish characters in memory at once shouldn't pose a problem on modern personal computers.

## Combining the files

You want the end result ordered (or maybe even sorted) by the line contents of `A.txt`. For not losing the relationship between the lines in `A.txt` and `B.txt` when changing their order, we need to combine their contents first.

Do that by

- opening both files without reading them yet
- opening a new file `AB.txt` for writing
- repeating the following until all of `A.txt` and `B.txt` have been processed:

  - reading a line of `A.txt`
  - reading a line of `B.txt`
  - append the combined content as a new line to `AB.txt`
  - discard what we've read so far from memory

If you know that a certain character (say, `'\t'`) cannot occur in `A.txt` you can use that as the separator:

```
with \
        open("A.txt") as a_file, \
        open("B.txt") as b_file, \
        open("AB.txt", "w") as ab_file:
    for a_line, b_line in zip(a_file, b_file):
        # get rid of the line endings, whatever they are
        a_line, = a_line.splitlines()
        b_line, = b_line.splitlines()

        # output the combined content to AB.txt
        print(f"{a_line}\t{b_line}", file=ab_file)
```

(Note that this relies on `zip` acting "lazy" and returning a generator rather than reading the files completely and returning a huge list as it would in Python 2.)

If all lines in `A.txt` have the same fixed length you don't need any separator at all. (For keeping your sanity while debugging, you might still want to use one, though.) If you don't know of any character that can't occur in `A.txt`, you can create a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer) and use [its `writerow` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.csvwriter.writerow) to write the lines to `AB.txt`. It will take care of the required escaping or quoting for you.

You might wonder where the step

> discard what we've read so far from memory

is implemented. This happens implicitly here, because the only variables that hold data from the files, `a_line` and `b_line` are overwritten for each iteration.

## Ordering the combined file

For ordering the whole file we have to completely load it into memory, right?

Nope. Well, actually yes, but again, not all of it at once. We can use [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). You can try to implement this yourself in Python, or you can just use the [UNIX command line tool `sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)) ([manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)), which does just that. On a Linux or macOS system, you already have it available. On Windows, it should be included in any UNIX emulator such as Cygwin or MinGW. If you already have Git installed with the default Git installer for Windows, you can use UNIX `sort` from the included "Git Bash".

Note that due to the order of our content within each line, the file will be sorted first by the content that came from `A.txt`, then (if that's the same) by the content that came from `B.txt`.

## Counting

Once you have the sorted combined file, you can again process it line-by-line but you have to keep *some* data around between the lines.

What we want to do is:

- For each block of subsequent lines with same A-content:

  - within that, for each block of subsequent lines with same B-content:
  - count its lines
  - keep tally of which B-content yet seen (within the A-content block) has had the most lines
  - at the end of the A-content block: output a line with the A-content and the most frequent B-content for that A-content

Because we can rely on the ordering we imposed above, this will produce the wanted result.

Something like this should work:

- read a line
- split it into A-content and B-content
- if the A-content is the same as on the previous line*:

  - if the B-content is the same as on the previous line*:

    - increase the counter for the current a-b-content combination
  - else (i.e., if the B-content is different than on the previous line):

    - store which B-content is the most seen so far and its tally

      - (it's either the previously most seen B-content or the one from the previous line)
    - reset the counter for the current a-b-content combination
    - increase that counter by one (for the current line)
    - store the B-content somewhere, so we can compare it to that of the next line in the next iteration
- else (i.e., if the A-content is different than on the previous line)**:

  - output the A-content of the previous line and the most seen B-content from the previous line
  - reset the counter for the current a-b-content combination
  - reset the information on what the most seen B-content was and its tally
  - store A-content and B-content of the current line, so they can be compared to those of the next line in the next iteration
- repeat until the whole file has been processed

* for the first line, this is implicitly `false`

** also do this when you've reached the end of the file

Actually implementing this is in Python left as an exerciser for the reader.  Note that you'll have to define some of the used variables before the step where they're mentioned in the description above for them to have the right scope.

Note that you can also do the counting step more cleverly than described here using capabilities of Python's comprehensive standard library. See [Heap Overflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60465092/674064) for a great example.

Comment: Good point, @HeapOverflow. [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) could indeed make the counting less unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

This option would not require the whole file in memory, but will need to keep a dictionary with A as keys and multiple dicts with B as keys. That can be simplified if you could hash or categorize the values (assigning an int  value to each unique A and for  each unique B).

Edit: Changed the dictionaries to use the hashed keys to reduce memory footprint at expense of CPU and changed output to show the lines to keep (as original A and B values are obfuscated)

Assuming my file is:

```
Lines,A.txt,B.txt
1,A,1
2,A,1
3,A,2
4,B,1
5,B,2
```

```
from collections import Counter
from csv import DictReader
_ = {}
_file = DictReader(open('abc.txt', 'r'), delimiter=',')

hash_to_line = {}
for row in _file:
    a = hash(row['A.txt'])
    b = hash(row['B.txt'])
    if a not in _:
        _[a] = Counter()
    if b not in _[a]:
        hash_to_line[(a, b)] = row['Lines']
    _[a][b] += 1

output = []
for A in _:
    _vals = list(_[A].values())
    _keys = list(_[A].keys())
    _max = max(_vals)

    _vals.index(_max)
    A, _[A][_keys[_vals.index(_max)]]
    output.append(hash_to_line[A, _keys[_vals.index(_max)]])
print('lines to keep:', output)
```

Replace the print with the appropriate storing of results.

Comment: Creating a dictionary with the contents of all the lines of a file as keys is potentially even worse than just storing the whole file in memory. Think about it…

Comment: Yes, but I am not doing that. I am not saving all the contents in a dict, it's a dict with keys the unique values of A and inside a counter with keys each unique B that is paired with B. The lower the amount of repetitions, the larger the size of the dict, that's true. For that reason I suggested to before hand hash or turn to categoricals the values to reduce the size

Comment: In a worse-case scenario all the lines of A could be unique. Even for less that worse-case, there could still be a very large number with each associated with a group of values.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware and I have addressed that in my comments and in the answer so that it's clear. Please, feel free to add a better solution so that we all can learn.

Comment: I have and idea for a possible answer, but am waiting for the OP to clarify an important detail before proposing it as a solution (if in fact it's applicable).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. About 1/3 of the file are duplicate lines, so it would still use too much memory if I use dictionary.

Comment: Check my latest edit, using hashed keys instead. Memory usage should drastically decrease and be bearable (under 1Gb peak usage for the process I would say)

Comment: Can you choose a different variable name for the dictionary currently called `_`? That makes the code kinda hard to read, especially since some of the other variables are prepended with that character.

Comment: If I change line 2 to `2,A,2`, it [still says](https://repl.it/repls/PureCrimsonComputing) to keep line 1 instead of line 2.

Comment: @HeapOverflow, good catch. I was only storing the first appearance of A.txt, not the pair of A.txt+B.txt. Should be fine now

Answer (score 1):

Building on [das-g's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60464376/674064), counting the combined and sorted lines with nested [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

# Combine and sort, in reality done like das-g described.
A = 'ABCDACADAEF'
B = '16781918216'
combined_and_sorted = sorted(zip(A, B))

# Count and produce the results
for a, agroup in groupby(combined_and_sorted, itemgetter(0)):
    bcounts = ((b, sum(1 for _ in group))
               for b, group in groupby(agroup, itemgetter(1)))
    print(a, max(bcounts, key=itemgetter(1))[0])
```

[Output](https://repl.it/repls/EvilCloudyCharacterset):

```
A 1
B 6
C 7
D 8
E 1
F 6
```

Comment: Is Python's `max(iterable)` lazy or would this still eat up a lot of memory if for some A values there are many different B values?

Comment: I thank both of you, and I will try the code later. Just for info, there are max 20 different B values for a A value. But same B value could occur up to 100000 times for some A value, but this isn't a problem for counter.

Comment: @das-g I'm not sure "lazy" is the right word, as `max` isn't a producer but a consumer. But yeah, it only keeps the single current maximum and [drops the previous one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f0cd3c61a5ae3aac5ebaccc75ae9828ca4f96c4/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1654-L1659) when it encounters a new one.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant to ask. And you're right that "lazy" probably isn't the right term for that. (Is there a short and commonly understood term for that kind of consumer behavior? Maybe a question for [cs.SE] Stack Exchange.)

Comment: @das-g Hmm, [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) and [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) come to mind, but meh...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I think using the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve-example) module would allow you to do what you want.

Here's a example implementation and its output. **Note** that I added four lines to the end of `A.txt` and `B.txt` to make sure the correct value was selected when it wasn't the first one encountered. **Also note** that I've left in development and debugging code in that you will definitely want to remove or disable before running it on really large input files.

As a table, the two input files looked like this:

```
 1 A 1
 2 B 6
 3 C 7
 4 D 8
 5 A 1
 6 C 9
 7 A 1
 8 D 8
 9 A 2
10 E 1
11 F 6
12 G 5
13 G 7
15 G 7
16 G 7
```

And, again as a table, here's what the two output files would be if they were rewritten:

```
1 A 1
2 B 6
3 C 7
4 D 8
5 E 1
6 F 6
7 G 7
```

---

```
import glob
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller
import os
import shelve


shelf_name = 'temp_shelf'
file_a_name = 'A.txt'
file_b_name = 'B.txt'


with open(file_a_name) as file_a, \
     open(file_b_name) as file_b, \
     shelve.open(shelf_name, flag='n', writeback=False) as shelf:

    for line, items in enumerate(zip(file_a, file_b)):
        x, fx = map(methodcaller('rstrip'), items)  # Remove line endings.
        d = shelf.setdefault(x, {})      # Each shelf entry is a regular dict.
        d[fx] = d.setdefault(fx, 0) + 1  # Update its value.
        shelf[x] = d                     # Update shelf.

        print('{!r} -> {!r}'.format(x, shelf[x]))

    # Show what ended up in shelf during development.
    print('\nFinal contents of shelf:')
    for k, d in shelf.items():
        print('  {!r}: {!r}'.format(k, d))

# Change file names to prevent overwriting originals during development.
file_a_name = 'A_updated.txt'
file_b_name = 'B_updated.txt'
comp_name = 'composite.txt'  # Used for development only.

# Update files leaving only most frequent combination.
with open(file_a_name, 'w') as file_a, \
     open(file_b_name, 'w') as file_b, \
     open(comp_name, 'w') as file_c, \
     shelve.open(shelf_name, flag='r') as shelf:

    for line, (k, d) in enumerate(shelf.items(), 1):
        file_a.write(k + '\n')
        fx = sorted(d.items(),  # Rev sort by number of occurrences.
                    key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0][0]  # Most common fx.
        file_b.write(fx + '\n')
        file_c.write('{} {} {}\n'.format(line, k, fx))  # For development only.

# CLean up by removing shelf files.
for filename in glob.glob(shelf_name + '.*'):
    print('removing', filename)
    os.remove(filename)

print('\nDone')
```